# Would it be wrong to say that the processor (and hardware) is the implementation of an interpreter for machine language?

Tags: automata, computer-architecture, compilers, interpreters

The question is basically in the title. I know that a computers hardware is of course some physical object, where as the interpreter is some abstract thing that does something abstract with the code it is given. Yet, can we say that the way the processor is build is the implementation of an interpreter?

Machine language is a sequence of physical states (0s and 1s ) on some physical memory, and if this physical states order follows certain rules (the syntax of the machine language) then the processor is build in a way that naturally leads to performing calculation steps (and changing some of the memory), e.g. "run" the programm.

As [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140023/what-other-implementation-styles-are-there-besides-compilation-interpretation-a/140099#140099) question's answer points out, compilers translate from one language to another, and interpreters for each language "run" the programm. It would be just consistent if this stretches down to machine language as well, and that's why I'm asking.

If one can make the analogy, when would it break down? What features of language semantics (given by the interpreter), for example expressions and values, are there that we can't find at the physical level anymore? In what way does the processor behave differently from what is expected of an interpreter?

Comment: The processor & hardware executes not just interprets

Comment: @ShAr can you be more specific? What does it do besides interpreting? What part of the processor action exceeds interpretation?

Comment: The interpreter is a system "program", it's a code at the end, that translates code of some languages, BASIC for example, and order the "processor", which is wires & ICs&... to execute it; all of this is done line by line

Comment: Is it a general feature of all interpreters that they translate code? What do they translate the code into?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp obviously, the interpreter "translates" the program into machine code. Actually, it would be more appropriate to say that it translates not the entire program, but the piece of program that it interprets at a given moment. It also does not create the "translated" machine code. It has all the possible pieces of required machine code already available, and when it interprets a part of the program it chooses the right piece of machine code and executes it.

Comment: @ShAr I wouldn't say there's any "translation" going on. That might be an (optional) part of an interpreter, to simplify program instructions before executing them, but at the core an interpreter *runs* a program, and it doesn't make any difference if it's running on silicon, in a virtual machine, or an entirely simulated environment.

Comment: So let's compare a compiler and an interpreter to an English-French translator. The compiler takes an entire program in English and translates it into French. Then someone can tell the processor to read the program in French out loud. On the other hand, the interpreter takes the program in English and after each phrase looks it up in a kind of English-French dictionary and immediately asks the processor to speak the French equivalent out loud. This "dictionary" is actually part of interpreter's own machine code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can terms "interpreter" and "processor" be used interchangably?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/can-terms-interpreter-and-processor-be-used-interchangably)

Comment: See also on StackOverflow [What is the relation between an interpreter and CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33756149/1048572), [Interpreters vs Compilers vs Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14678060/1048572) and SoftwareEngineering [Does an interpreter produce machine code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/300593/66652) or [When an interpreter executes code: Is there a "chain of interpretations" down to the lowest level?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/231777/66652)

Comment: To make it even more complicated, "microcode" is a bit of software deeply embedded into the CPU, often used as an interpreter for old and obsolete instructions.

Comment: Yes, it's a perfectly reasonably way of describing it: although whether it's useful depends on what you're trying to get across to your reader. It depends partly on whether you're trying to explain things at a level of abstraction where you can ignore details such as firmware/microcode.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not such a bad way of looking at things.

On most modern CPUs, the instruction set architecture (ISA for short) is abstract, in the sense that it doesn't dictate that it must be implemented using certain hardware techniques or it is not a compliant implementation. Nothing in the ISA specification specifies whether or not it uses register renaming, or branch prediction, or whether vector instructions are parallel or pipeline-streaming, or even whether the core is scalar or superscalar.

Indeed, on many modern CPUs, there is a certain amount of translation from the ISA into an internal representation to be executed more efficiently, such as Intel's micro-operations ([uOps for short](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/cpu-metrics-reference/uops.html)).

Comment: Does the ISA being abstract make it less quIalified for being an interpreter? Do interpreters implementations usually comply to some standard? I try to understand how the information you gave fit's into my question.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp I think what Pseudonym meant is actually contrary to what you wrote: the ISA being abstract makes the hardware *more* qualified to be regarded as an interpreter

Comment: Exactly that. It may be useful to compare with more specialised ISAs (e.g. those of microcontrollers), where worst-case cycle counts form part of the specification. This can sometimes be important, for example in certain hard real-time applications where worst-case interrupt delivery time must be minimised. In situations like this, it does partly dictate what kind of hardware technology can be used to implement the instruction set.

Comment: I worry that this answer is a bit [homuncular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_argument); are micro-operations interpreted?

Comment: @Corbin good point ;-): The OP was asking about the bare metal and is diverted to the description of another abstract machine. But I think the point is that what you "code assembler against" *is always* an abstract machine, and the hardware factually interprets it -- be it because it directly executes literally what's coded or because it transforms it again beforehand. A good example of the idea is a [Lisp machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) which does a lot of the interpreting work in hardware. One could still say "it interprets Lisp".

Comment: I would have said the execution decoder acts more like a compiler, but that's just me. Now when you get to the microcoded instructions, those are clearly interpreted.

Comment: @Joshua There is a fuzzy line between "compiler" and "interpreter", but the way I usually use the terms is whether translation is static (ahead of time) or dynamic (as execution proceeds).

Comment: @Pseudonym: "There is a fuzzy line" is the key here; too often, students get distracted by trying to find precise definitions of concepts which are inherently fuzzy, and whose precise definitions really don't matter. At least IMO. Anyway, to make the line fuzzier in this case, the x86 CPU probably "JIT compiles" the ops into a small cache of µops which can be executed without further compilation (or whatever you want to call it) as long as the cache isn't needed for new instructions, thus reducing decoding work for tight loops.

Comment: @ Pseudonym and @ciamej I think I get it: You argue that the ISA is abstract, and that makes the hardware more qualified, because the term "interpreter" is usually used to "run" code (which is an abstract thing as well). Is that the right unterstanding?

Answer (score 8):

No, it would not be wrong. Indeed, we can use the [Futamura projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation#Futamura_projections) to help us understand the situation.

The first Futamura projection says that if we specialize hardware with some native machine code, then we get a standalone executable. For example, classic video-game consoles combined an interpreter in the console with native code in each game cartridge, so that plugging a cartridge into a console resulted in an executable system. As other answers point out, computability theory implies that we can write (slow) software which is equivalent to the hardware in effects, and indeed emulators exist for most classic consoles.

Edit: A Futamura specializer is a specific sort of program which takes two unevaluated programs and returns their composition. Sometimes it is called a Kleene compositor due to its relationship with [Kleene's parameter theorem (the $S^m_n$ theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem). For more details, see [Piponi](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/05/three-projections-of-doctor-futamura.html) (with helpful pictures); for even more details, see ["Partial Evaluation and Automatic Program Generation"](https://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/pebook/). In older computers, inserting a cartridge would close electronic circuits, connecting daughterboard to motherboard and allowing all of the chips in the cartridge to communicate with the chips in the host. This is Futamura specialization; a piece of non-functional hardware was added to existing hardware in order to create a system which is limited in functionality but relatively fast at execution.

The second Futamura projection says that if we specialize the specialization process itself with the interpreter as the curried argument, then we get a compiler. I'll extend the video-game example. A local bar has a large selection of classic games; if we ask the bartender to load a cartridge, then the bartender will allocate a console and deliver controllers. In essence, the bartender is a Futamura compiler.

Less facetiously, we could imagine a compiler in the traditional sense, compiling high-level programmer expressions to native code, but generated using Futamura projections. If this compiler's underlying interpreter is some hardware, then this implies that the compiler will directly call that hardware in order to partially evaluate the static parts of its input programs. And, if one thinks about it for a moment, any partially-evaluating compiler is doing something morally equivalent to this; Futamura would just require that the emulation of instructions is done in a faithful way, using instructions equivalent to the original hardware.

Comment: When you say "native code" in this context, you're talking about custom-designed *hardware*, e.g. to accelerate some portion of the game logic?  The question is already talking about CPUs executing machine code, although 8-bit micros (including those used in early game consoles) often were microcoded designs, where being an "interpreter" for machine code was in some ways an accurate description of how the hardware really worked.

Comment: @PeterCordes: "native code" is a synonym for machine code. Also, as I pointed out in another comment, it is a homuncular fallacy to believe that a hardware interpreter's internal design is relevant, even when it defines micro-operations.

Comment: Oh, so when you say "specialize", you mean "provide code for, making the generic game console into an implementation of an Asteroids, Breakout, or Super Mario Bros game machine".  Ok, I see how your terminology works now.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It sounds like you grok it, but it was far too difficult, and for that I apologize. I've added the word "machine" to "native code", and I've added an entire paragraph about Futamura specialization with external resources. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: What about the Futurama Projections?

Answer (score 7):

You could look at it that way. But traditionally, the term "interpreter" is usually used to refer to software, not hardware.

There are CPU emulators, these can definitely be considered to be interpreters of the processor machine language.

The distinction between hardware and software implementations is useful in practice because it dictates how easy it is to make changes. If there's a bug in a hardware CPU, you will likely have to replace the computer or processor chip to address it (unless there are software workarounds). But if there's a problem in a software interpreter, you can just install an update (which has become easier over the years, as digital media became more compact and then migrated to Internet distribution). This means that hardware development requires more stringent specifications and testing -- bugs that make it to customers are much more serious and costly to resolve.

Comment: Modern x86 CPUs support microcode updates specifically because of the reason you mention: after being bitten by the FDIV and `F00F` bugs in P5 Pentium, P6 made it possible for microcode updates to change some things that weren't totally fixed-function.

Comment: e.g. Skylake had several bugs, including some real-world bugs (not just theoretical code sequences nobody would ever run) that were worked around by disabling some parts of the hardware, leaving some performance pot-holes like [branches in the last bytes of a 32-byte block](//stackoverflow.com/a/62306482/224132) because the microcode update disabled the uop cache (DSB) for such blocks, or disabling the loop buffer because of a partial-register merging corner case that went wrong with it enabled. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#.C2.B5OP-Fusion_.26_LSD

Comment: But yes, updateable microcode can only do so much; there's still fixed hardware, and you have to consider things you're going to let microcode disable in case some future problem is found. Thus proper Meltdown mitigation required new CPUs or a software workaround; it was a whole new unanticipated class of vulnerability.  And yeah, CPU vendors do extensive verification testing. (Intel got slack about that for Skylake -> more bugs than in past designs.)  Related: https://danluu.com/cpu-bugs/ and https://www.zdnet.com/article/ex-intel-engineer-apple-turned-away-from-intel-over-skylake-cpu-bugs/

Comment: Yeah, microcode just pushes it one level down. There's also FPGA, but it's not feasible to use them to implement a full CPU instruction set, so they're used for specialized co-processors.

Comment: "pushes it one level down" - you're talking about traditional microcode like 6502 and Z80?   And yes, in terms of answering this question, that's a great example; a simpler hard-wired CPU and a table of microcode.  But Intel's "microcode" updates aren't *just* the Microcode Sequencer ROM contents (which gets used for some complex instructions like `cpuid` or `lock cmpxchg`).  It also apparently can toggle controls for the state of how some logic blocks behave or interact, perhaps with something like an FPGA gate at a few key points designed ahead of time to have fallback modes of operation.

Comment: If you mean "pushes down" the place where a problem is unfixable via updates, I don't think it's quite that simple.  Modern Intel / AMD CPUs are *not* what you'd describe as a "microcoded design" in the sense that every instruction invokes a sequence of micro-ops.  (Common instructions decode to 1 uop, and the common case fast paths are mostly hard wired.  e.g. I don't think a microcode update could make `add` decode as `sub`.  Adding a new "instruction" for Spectre mitigation (flushing BTB) was done by adding a new MSR (model specific register number) as a way to get new microcode executed.)

Comment: What I meant was that eventually you get to the HW that executes the microcode.

Comment: Ah, then yeah you were talking about actual microcoded CPUs like 8086, 6502, and Z80, not like Intel P6 / SandyBridge / Skylake. Only a few instructions are microcoded in that sense, and the kinds of tweaks that updates usually make to work around errata usually aren't involved in the microcode that gets executed to implement an instruction. (Although that did happen with SKL, where an update strengthened `mfence` by adding what's probably just an `lfence` uop to its microcode. [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40409297) has erratum numbers)

Comment: In other words, the name "microcode update" is not very accurate or descriptive of all the things it can do on modern Intel/AMD CPUs. But it needs a name, and that's unique, and close enough to accurate to work in a "lies to children".  As I said, I think the reality is that includes some FPGA-like reconfig of a few key pieces of logic, or just setting some bits that are maybe inputs to AND or OR gates in parts of the pipeline to make something always-false or always-true instead of pass-through.

Comment: Indeed, and my answer was also a similar approximation of the real thing.

Comment: Yeah, your actual answer is ok, and I think so are my comments on how adding some toggles lets CPU vendors mitigate *some* design bugs that slip through the extensive verification testing they need to do.  I just wanted to make it clear (to future readers) that modern x86 CPUs aren't simply microcoded the way 6502 is, because that's a common misconception when people hear about how modern x86 decodes to uops.  Also that microcode updates can work around some bugs in the "fixed function" logic, if the risk was anticipated and the CPU can still function another way.

Answer (score 4):

You can build any program as a circuit, check e.g. most texts on computability, they often discuss circuit complexity for solving problems in addition to the more traditional Turing machine models (closer to normal programs). For some problems it makes economic/performance sense to create a custom circuit (look e.g. at [FPLGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)), most of the time it is much cheaper/flexible to just write a program for a more or less general purpose CPU.

If your CPU is build as a fixed circuit, is a microprogram for a more basic CPU, programmed into a FPLGA, or as [a program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) running on some CPU is really irrelevant. All are doing the job of interpreting the instructions.

Answer (score 4):

> If one can make the analogy, when would it break down? What features of language semantics (given by the interpreter), for example expressions and values, are there that we can't find at the physical level anymore? In what way does the processor behave differently from what is expected of an interpreter?

It's a bit of a semantic argument, but "language semantics" themselves don't exist at the physical level; there are physical states and transformations to which we assign a meaning.

You can generally find *values* in a processor all the way down to the bit level of individual transistors. However *expressions* get dematerialised. Instead you will find a set of enable and selector bits that route the values to a logic block which computes a function, then routes the result to a destination.

There are also processor features that don't map cleanly to language features. Out-of-order execution and speculative execution, for example. Speculative execution in particular is *supposed* to be entirely hidden from the programmer's model but in some circumstances has been used as a security exploit (SPECTRE).

Interrupts and aborts are also outside the simple machine code model, as they provide forced control flow transfer to a different bit of machine code.

Comment: OoO exec and pipelining in general are equivalent to the "as-if" rule: the code must execute *as if* each instruction was executed one at a time, in program order, before starting the next instruction. (Assuming a normal ISA, not a VLIW with explicit groups that execute in parallel like IA-64.)  Maintaining this illusion is the cardinal rule of OoO exec.  But just like in C and C++, the illusion is only maintained for the current core; other cores are allowed to see out memory operations appear out of order, unless barrier instructions (or the ISA's memory ordering rules) prevent it.

Comment: (Some ISAs have restrictions on valid instruction sequences, e.g. ISAs with a branch-delay slot such as MIPS typically don't allow another branch in the delay slot: that causes unpredictable behaviour.  Same for MIPS I with its load-delay slot: trying to read a load result in the next instruction would expose your code to the microarchitectural effects, e.g. reading the old reg value on a cache hit, else on cache miss it would stall and the next instruction would read the load result.  MIPS I was only implemented on simple in-order pipelines; later MIPS had interlocks to stall there.)

Answer (score 4):

If you look too much at words, they'll scurry away. In general the boundaries
on meanings of words are soft.

As others said, you are not wrong. But, the word *interpreter* is usually used precisely to mean "not the CPU".

How does an interpreter *effectively* carry out its interpretation? What is it interpreting *on*? (Or *into*?)

As the word is customary used, an interpreter is a bunch of instructions carrying out some other bunch of instructions (the program), but the effective execution of the interpreter code is done by something else (the CPU).

I do not know the details of CPUs inner workings, but at some point (say, after microcode translation) "instructions" turn into activation of different parts of the CPU, data turns into state of internal registers, some circuits are activated, producing (physical) internal states transitions, some internal communication lines (buses) are activated or disabled, states are moved from one register to another or to memory, [much more complicated real stuff omitted], and that's execution.

Answer (score 3):

TLDNR: No, not wrong.

The words we use are part of communication: you think - you say - I hear - I interpret. Depending on the context the word "interpreter" may be understood quite differently. So be careful when talking and writing, we do have different bakgrunds and different ways of interpreting words.

In my world, an interpreter is most often a software program so I could become confused. But let´s dive a little deeper.

.1 Executing the machine code: Yes the hardware fetches bits from memory and "interprets" them as code and then does what the code says, perhaps multiplying the values in two registers. A software interpreter would do the same. The hardware does some extra things a "pure" software cannot really do, such as consuming power from the power source and creating intended and unintended signals and electrical noise. It is not unusual for hardware designers to experience bugs due to these unintended things, especially in the edge case of supply voltages or temperatures.

NOTE: both hardware and software interpreters may container bugs of course, but that is a different story...

.2 Executing the machine code in detail: You might know of the Intel CPU-s used in a lot of computers, say the 10th generation i9. This computer executes x86 instructions (I am simplifying here, but bare with me). The x86 instructions are actually "translated" and "reordered" inside the i9 CPU before actually beeing executed. This translation process, from one assembly language to the interna language of the processor may be seen as an interpreter if you wish. The reason for the complicated multistage pipeline with translation and reordering is in order to gain performance.

.3 Conclusion: No, you are not wrong to see the hardware as an interpreter. But beware that this is not the common language usage, so you may end up confusing the listener or reader. I would stay away from using words that way, but that is me.

Comment: Most common x86 instructions decode to a single micro-op (but yes some are 2 or 3, and a few rare ones are a lot more).  These uops then go through the rest of the superscalar OoO exec pipeline just like in an equivalent AArch64 or MIPS R10k or something, with reordering of exec happening just based on the availability of inputs (to hide latency e.g. cache misses) https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ and  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/.  If you want a CPU that really "interprets" by running different micro-programs for each opcode, look at 6502 or Z80, or 8086.

Answer (score 3):

You can call everything everything - in 2021, all of our components (CPUs, machine code, compilers, interpreters) share so many aspects, that you'll find an argument in almost any direction. Maybe it would not be quite wrong to call a CPU an interpreter, but I feel it would be very weird and discount what actual interpreters are about in the first place.

An all-purpose CPU stupidly *executes* its instructions. If we ignore advanced current-days aspects of lookahead and heavy parallelization - i.e., think of an old, extremely simple, 6502 CPU instead of a current Intel or ARM offering - then you see that the CPU looks at one specific point in RAM or ROM, fetches one instruction, then executes that extremely simple instruction. There is nothing between this execution and the electrons running around on the hardware - at this low level, the machine code *is* the electronic layer.

So, no, in general I would say the processor is an *executor*, not an *interpreter*.

Modern aspects could change this. For example, you could create a CPU which understands CISC commands, but does this by running a microcode preprocessor inside the CPU which translates those CISC commands into RISC commands, which then are executed on the actual machinery of the CPU. In this case you could say the the CPU *interprets* CISC code. I would accept this *especially* in the case that this preprocessor has larger state than just the next command; i.e. if it does complex decisions based on previous and next statements. This also leads to branch prediction, parallelization, power management and so on - complex "management" efforts which may be reordering or optimizing the stream of incoming machine commands. This "preprocessor" then would be an interpreter, shoveling commands to its internal execution engine.

An actual interpreter earns its designation by looping over some more abstract representation of a program (sometimes this can be the source code directly, for example in certain scripting languages close to a shell; sometimes bytecode which can be generated upfront (e.g. Java) or on the fly (e.g. Ruby, Perl)). A common theme is that this bytecode is often compatible between different interpreters; famously you can run Java bytecode anywhere from big servers to embedded little machines, which may have nothing much in common on the machine language level.

Finally, all of this is a moving target anyway, since on each level of abstraction, we are combining all kinds of techniques. Your Java interpreter might have a Just-in-time compiler and your pieces of "bytecode" might in fact just be a compiled-in-the-meantime machine code. Your state-of-the-art CPU might have an interpretion layer for compatibility for some generation of CPU 20 years ago. Your compiler might have a compile-time interpreter able to modify compilation in some way, etc.

Comment: You mean "interprets CISC"?

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence - surely we cannot call a CPU a compiler. Yes, there's hardly any difference (or rather, a foggy line) between an *executor* and an *interpreter*. The latter often **contains** a preprocesssor or compiler, but it isn't one.

Comment: I've strategically injected a word "almost" in that sentence, @Bergi. --- Yes, thanks JDługosz.

Comment: @Bergi: Most CPUs aren't compilers, but Transmeta Crusoe basically was: dynamic recompilation to an internal VLIW, caching those optimized "compilation" results of their "Code Morphing Software".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta_Crusoe.  (And before anyone mentions it, this is *very* different from how modern Intel/AMD decode x86 instructions to one (or sometimes more) micro-ops to run through the rest of the superscalar OoO exec pipeline, even with SnB or Zen's uop cache (https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/) or even P4's trace cache.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I maintain the distinction that the Transmeta Crusoe was not a compiler - it did *contain* a compiler. Next to all the other stuff like the execution unit. Together, all these parts compose an *interpreter* (for x86, for Java, or other ISAs).

Comment: @Bergi: yes, that's a better description, thanks.  A whole system including dynamic recompilation and a CPU, packaged up as a CPU which implements another ISA.  Otherwise CPUs really don't involve compilation in the sense of translation that's aware of things across multiple "source" (machine code) statements at all.  CPU = compiler could only be said to apply for a purely *virtual* CPU like Apple's Rosetta / Rosetta-2 (which can recompile whole programs before running them, not just JIT), or QEMU's dynamic translation.  But the context here didn't seem to be virtual CPUs.

Comment: [Profile guided optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) starts to move/blur a compiler a (very) little towards an interpreter. Also, flow analysis is somewhat like interpretation.

Comment: @Bergi A CPU is a compiler that compiles machine code into results. :-P  Yeah, bad joke.

Comment: @PabloH Not just that, but also macro languages (code preprocessing, macro expansion) and [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) are interpretation that happens during compilation. Still, these shouldn't have side effects and are only *part* of a compiler, the input language code itself is only compiled but not interpreted: the result of compilation is another ("executable") code.

Comment: "There is nothing between this execution and the electrons running around on the hardware - at this low level, the machine code is the electronic layer." - This is precisely why I was tempted to say "The interpreter is the processor". 

From what you wrote, your argument is that an interpreter processes abstract code, and then tells the hardware how to behave, instead of being the hardware itself, is that right?

Answer (score -1):

If the hardware alone can interpret anything, yes. But with modern electronic digital data-processing the software is separate from the hardware. Even the BIOS or UEFI uses code.

In the mid-Twentiethh Century, the programmer actually rearranged the memory.  So the memory was the program. There was no storage, per se. That was WHEN the Chairman of IBM speculated, given time, it might be possible to build a computer that weighed under 5 tons!

Given that he also predicted the world market might reach 8, eight computers in the entire world that is, he was a little off! So, if you have no code in the BIOS cmos memory, nothing stored on anything, just hardware and electricity, and 'that' can interpret; the answer to your question is 'yes'.

Otherwise, it is 'no'.

Comment: "In the mid-Ninteenth Century" ... is when the American Civil War took place, almost a century before computers were invented.

Comment: It was when a member of nobility died who became famous for musing about human flight and the use of computing machinery beyond number crunching.

Comment: In addition to having the wrong century, the limitations on computers that you speak about only apply to the ENIAC, which wasn't quite general purpose. The anecdote about Thomas Watson and the market for computers [seems to be a myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_J._Watson#Post-World_War_II) and you also seem to be attributing to him a misquoted version of a much-reproduced 1949 Popular Mechanics quote ("Where a calculator like ENIAC today is equipped with 18,000 vacuum tubes and weighs 30 tons, computers in the future may have only 1000 vacuum tubes and perhaps weigh only 1½ tons.")

Comment: The BIOS (or UEFI firmware) is not part of the CPU / processor.  Firmware is just software that comes with the system, and runs when it first boots.  Having some firmware on a ROM on the motherboard is a fundamentally different thing from how the CPU fetches, decodes, and executes instructions (whether it's from that ROM, or more code from RAM loaded there directly or indirectly by the firmware).

Comment: I get where're you're going at: You want to tell me that for my bit of machine code to be run, the processor needs additional code that tells it what to do with my code.

Comment: In the current data-processing model, much to do with object-oriented programming, software and hardware are thought of as separate things. Much like stacks, the model is only for conceptual use. The actual bits are not in a   physical stack. Processor 'registers' are also conceptual constructs. The bits are not arranged in a linear format inside the cpu. So, I guess since it is constructs that serve the imagination of the computer scientist, hardware could be imagined to interpret.